# Cloud Functions for Firebase: get deltaValue from snapshot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Via the client I make an update on a database reference (imagePaths in this case, which holds a bunch of key values). via data.val and data.previous.val I have access to both the old and new values.

Is there any way do get direct access to the delta value (in this case, the deleted key/value pair. As shown in the image there is a "_delta", but I cannot figure out how to get access.

My goal is obviously to get that value of the on deleted, but I hope there is some better way than comparing old & new to figure out the missing one.

[image: console.log(event.data.previous.val()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect there was a key deleted, you can iterate the keys `event.data.previous` and use the [changed()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#changed) method to figure out if something there changed before examining it any further.